# express validator invalid email error on certain devices

Tags: node.js, validation, express

This error only happens on mobile devices and so far only on Samsung devices. I have tested on an old Motoralla device using Android 4. something and it works fine. The newer Android 6 on the Samsung device gives the error. I am using [express validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) which is middleware for [validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js)

The error that appears is "Invalid email address"

```
body('email', 'Invalid email address.')
    .normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false })
    .isEmail()
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
        return User.findOne({ email: value })
            .then(userDoc => {
                if (userDoc) {
                    return Promise.reject('Email address unavailable.');
                };
            });
    }),
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this only happens on some Samsung mobile phones.

Comment: Remove your validator and check your getting value on `req,body.email` for all device

Comment: Removing `.normalizeEmail()` completely seems to have solved the issue but this isn't ideal as I would like it in there.

Comment: I am asking to check whether your getting data after removing validation

Comment: Okay, I will try that

Comment: Yes, I did a console.log in my controller and I get a value for the email.

Comment: post the value that works on device and value that not worked in device, Include type of value using `typeof`